# Command line NSIS script compilation - silent option

Tags: command-line, installation, nsis

I would like to make my installer silent. I would like to have flexibility to make installer silent or not depending on a command line option. In doc, I have found this to launch NSIS script compilation:

```
"C:\Program Files\NSIS\makensis.exe" "D:\Produts\folder\Install\nsis\MyApp.nsi"
```

this is working. By default, this is generating a non silent installer. To have a silent installer (with a command line option only), i tried this

```
"C:\Program Files\NSIS\makensis.exe" \S "D:\Produts\folder\Install\nsis\MyApp.nsi"
```

but \S is not a recognized option. How can i make installer silent with command line option?

I can find this  in doc

> 4.8.1.36 SilentInstall
>
> normal|silent|silentlog Specifies whether or not the installer should
>   be silent. If it is 'silent' or 'silentlog', all sections that have
>   the SF_SELECTED flag are installed quietly (you can set this flag
>   using SectionSetFlags), with no screen output from the installer
>   itself (the script can still display whatever it wants, use
>   MessageBox's /SD to specify a default for silent installers). Note
>   that if this is set to 'normal' and the user runs the installer with
>   /S (case sensitive) on the command line, it will behave as if
>   SilentInstall 'silent' was used. Note: see also LogSet.
>
> See section 4.12 for more information.

so that i feel abused

Or should some instruction be added to NSIS script, so that compilation is receptive to /S option ?

Tried it with -S and not working either.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/S` option is available for your installer, not the `makensis.exe`. So you can run the installer in silent mode from commandline:
`MyApp.exe /S`

In case you want *to build installer to be always silent*, you can use following technique:

In the `.onInit` function:

```
Function .onInit
  !ifdef IsSilent
    SetSilent silent
  !endif
FunctionEnd
```

And then build the installer with `/D` option to define the `IsSilent` constant:

`makensis.exe /DIsSilent MyApp.nsi`

That means, in case you build with `/D` option like above, the installer will be always silent; without `/D` option your installer will be non-silent by default and still you can run it from commandline `MyApp.exe /S` to be silent.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. where should i  put the .onInit function? at the beginning of MyApp.nsi ? the .nsi file is calling lots of other files (.nsh) with section and function definitions inside. Will the silent mode apply for the whole script and dependencies if i only define silent mode once in onInit function? thanks!!

Comment: can i have alternatively `Function .onInit IfSilent +2 SetSilent silent FunctionEnd` ?

Comment: The `.onInit` is installer callback function so it will be called automatically in exactly defined phase of the installer run. I guess it doesn't really matter where defined. Surely it apply to whole installer.

Comment: it seems that when i have cmd line `makensis.exe MyApp.nsi`, install is silent as well

Comment: from your post i understand: if i compile nsis script with `"makensis.exe" "MyApp.nsi"` (without \D), then i have default installation non silent (with `"MyApp.exe"`) and silent on demand (with `"MyApp.exe" \S`). if i compile nsis script with  `"makensis.exe" \D IsSilent "MyApp.nsi"`, then install is always silent. do i miss something?

Comment: You understand correctly, but several issues: You have to use forward slash (instead of backslash) in all cases, i.e. `/S`, `/D` and when spefifying `IsSilent` constant via commandline it must be without space: `makensis.exe /DIsSilent MyApp.nsi`.

Comment: Excuse me, the code you posted in the second comment will not work! In this case the installer will be still silent, of course... Use `!ifdef` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: yes, but the following one works (tested) `Function .onInit IfSilent 0 +2 SetSilent silent FunctionEnd`, shame on me

Comment: do you know how to do to set the install dir path with command line ? i have read something like `\D "my_path"` but what should i insert in nsis script so that it works ? such as `!ifndef InstallDir InstallDir "default_path" !endif`, and it is defined with command line, then it is the command line path. could you help here?

Comment: `/D=path_with_no_quote` is doing great, must be in the end, no quotes at all even if spaces. thanks for tips ovreall

Comment: may i ask one more question: `cmdline = '""%s" /S"' % (uninst)` what is the double quote `'""` for at beginning of this string? is it made to append a 'current directory path' ?

Comment: `/D=` for `InstDir` should work as you described. The last issue you wrote I don't understand, perhaps should be more elaborated in separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to COMPILE the NSI script silently from a command line, that is not the same as having the installer run silently.

In my compile batch scripts, I use:

```
c:\progra~1\nsis\makensis /V0 .\sample.nsi | findstr /b /r /c:"YouCantFindMe"
```

The `/V#` option suppresses all output but still includes a ribbon/banner when the compiler starts (see NSIS command line option documentation.  Piping all output through "findstr" suppresses that output as well.

Comment: This does not do what OP wants (make installer silent), but helped me (make my compiler silent). Thanks. More here http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html